# how can I extract Calgary from the Source HTML below using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have many tds in a page. How can I extract "Calgary" from source HTML. I only know the inputs id in advanced.

```
<td class="Form">Calgary<input type="text" style="display:none" class="Large" value="408028" id="branchid" name="branchid"></td>
```

The code I tried:

```
$('#branchid').parent().find("td:first").html();
```

Comment: `$('#branchid').parent()` is the `td` and `find('td')` would return nothing. Just do `.parent().text()`

Comment: `$('#branchid').prop('previousSibling').nodeValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.trim($('#branchid').parent().text())
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 0):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/2SqLS/

just use :

```
$('#branchid').parent().text()
```